How to set up webhooks for new events in Google Calendar using Google Calendar API?
I'm developing an application that integrates with Google Calendar, and I need to receive real-time notifications whenever a new event is created in a user's calendar. I have enabled the Google Calendar API and set up OAuth 2.0 for authentication, I need to get notifications or fetch events from Google Calendar as soon as they are created.
I tried using the Google Calendar Event watch API,but not able to find any details or an event id in the notification.
